# Searching through loaded data and displaying similar items in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I currently have a page titled news.php, this page displays my news articles. I am now planning to allow my users to search through the database preventing constant scrolling. In doing so I have created a second file called search.php. My intention with this page is to load in articles 'LIKE' the submission from my form in news.php on this page. I have no errors in my error.log and I am having trouble submitting the information and loading search.php displaying my results. I have found tones of information on mysqli but nothing for PDO. So in short, how do I take the user to search.php and displaying similar information to their submission in my form on news.php?

php on search.php html of form on news.php is displayed bellow

```
<div id="news">
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE headline LIKE '%$search%' OR dateTime LIKE '%$    search%' OR text LIKE '%$search%'");
    $q->execute(array($search));

      if ($q->rowCount() > 0){
        while ($result = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); {
            echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 height-news">';
            echo '<p class="news-title">'.$results[$i]['headline'].'<br>'.'</p>';
            echo '<img class="news-img" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $results[$i]['logo']).    '"/>';
            echo '<p class="news-time">'.$results[$i]['dateTime'].'<br>'.'</p>';
            echo '<p class="news-body">'.$results[$i]['text'].'</p>';
            echo '<button class="news-btn" id="myBtn" onclick="showFull(this)">Read More</button>'.'</div>    ';
          }
        if ($result == 0) {
            echo '<p class="error-message3">Sorry there is no results!</p>';
        }  
    }
}
?>
```

```
<div class="searchPanel">

<div id="x-gon">
  <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
</div>

<form action="search.php" id="content" method="POST">
<input  type="text" name="search" type="text" class="input420"></input>


<submit id="CupidsArrow" class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-4x" type="submit" name="submit-search" value="Submit"></submit>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<i id="CupidsArrow" class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-4x" name="submit-search"></i></a>
```

here you are using a `i` tag to submit the form with an `a` tag. And also `</a>` is there but its opening tag is missing. So instead of this, try:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-search" value="Submit" />
```

`input` type `submit` will submit the form to the url specified in the form action.

Ex:

```html
<form action="search.php" id="content" method="POST">
  <input />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, i have made these changes, it has been a long day. However this has not effected the performance of the code.

Comment: Your code is not working or you are dealing with performance tuning?

Comment: not performance tuning, i meant the form submission is not working,

Comment: @nerdychick you can accept the answer if you think it will help you, as it will help the other community member

Comment: `name="name="submit-search"` is a syntax error, btw.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sharp eyes :P

Answer (score 0):

```
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    function showFull(button) {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      $('.dimmer').show();
      var newsText = $(button).parent().find(".news-title")[0];
      $(".news-title2").text(newsText.textContent);
      var newsDate = $(button).parent().find(".news-time")[0];
      $(".news-time2").text(newsDate.textContent);
      var newsBody = $(button).parent().find(".news-body")[0];
      $(".news-body2").text(newsBody.textContent);
      var newsImg = $(button).parent().find(".news-img")[0].src;
      $('.news-img2').attr("src", newsImg);
    }

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```
<div class="searchPanel animated bounceInLeft">

<div id="x-gon">
  <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
</div>

<form action="search.php" id="content" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search" type="text" class="input420"></input>

<input type="submit" name="submit-search" value="Submit" id="CupidsArrow" class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-4x"></input>
</form>
</div>
```